# Laravel Model::create() returns the wrong id

Tags: laravel-8

For some unknown reason, the primary key value being returned after Model::create() is not the primary key value in the database. I have tried setting "incrementing" to false as I have found that that worked for other people, but no deal for me.

Laravel Framework 8.34.0

**Model**

```
class Provider extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'DoctorFacility';
    public $primaryKey = 'DoctorFacilityId';
    //public $incrementing = false; // tried this it just made the primary key empty
}
```

**Controller**

```
use App\Models\Provider;

class ProviderController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        new Provider;
        $result = Provider::create([
            'first_name' => 'Jane',
            'last_name' => 'Doe'
        ]);

        // returns 45004857 the first test, and 45004859 on the 
        // second test (so it is incrementing in some way?)
        // while the actual id of the last created record
        // is "62644" on the first test, and "62645" on
        // the second test. 
        Log::critical($result->DoctorFacilityId); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your migration?

Comment: I doubt that it is the problem, but [the Laravel docs show `$primaryKey` should be protected](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys), not public.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: updated to not use a get after adding as stated.

As stated in the official Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserts): if you use the create method, you will need to specify a fillable or guared property on your model class.

Update your model to use protected instead of public for the fillable array and also make sure to add the values you are filling to the fillable array.

In my experience with using composite primarykeys the value was not always directly available after doing a `create` of or `save`. I understand this is not a composite, but it is a custom value for your primary key.

**Database:**

Change your database table 'DoctorFacility' to use a column named 'id' as primary key.

**Model:**

```
class Provider extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'DoctorFacility';
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name']
}
```

**Controller**

```
$result = Provider::create([
            'first_name' => 'Jane',
            'last_name' => 'Doe'
        ]);

Log::critical($result->id);
```

Comment: $fillable is protected, and $fillable is set.  DoctorFacilityId is set to auto increment and is working as described in the code comments in the original question.  Looks like this... 

```
protected $fillable = [
        'PVId',
        'Type',
        'Created',
        'CreatedBy',
        'LastModified',
        'LastModifiedBy',
    ];
```

Comment: I tried changing the syntax to $provider->save() and I get the same result.   Log::critical(@$provider->DoctorFacilityId); // = 45005619, and the DoctorFacilityId in the database is returned as "63602"

Comment: Ok, in your question it doesn't show that $fillable is set, that's why I mentioned it. I know it is protected, but you can still add it as protected in your model, it will overwrite it's parent class's value. What is the PVId in your fillable array, is this a different value than the DoctorFacilityId? Why not use default value of 'id' for your database table?

Comment: Can you check if the model uses the correct value for the primary key? You can run (new Provider)->->getKeyName(); for this. 
If it is incorrect, update the public $primaryKey to protected $primaryKey in your model and try again.

Comment: As Lars asked, can you clarify what `PVId` is? Also, the `$fillable` you've shown does not include either `first_name` or `last_name`, so your code should not actually be able to create a record at all?  And lastly, just to be absolutely clear, can you clarify exactly how you are getting the ID when you say "*the DoctorFacilityId in the database is returned as "63602"*"?

Comment: re: exactly how you are getting the ID when you say "the DoctorFacilityId in the database is returned as "63602""   ... I see that as the value shown in the log, eg. Log::critical(), but when I query the db directly, I see that it is not the value for that field on that latest record.

Comment: The edited answer where you just select what you hope is the last one inserted, of course works but isn't really a solution or answer to the question because it's just a hope that there isn't someone else hitting insert at the same time.

Comment: I agree it is not the best solution. If you don't want that: don't use custom Id, but use a column 'id' in your database and don't override the value in the model. You didn't answer on questions asked by either Don't Panic or myself, that's why I was trying to find a different solution for you.